# Codeigniter with different domains

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm looking to try and use codeigniter with different domains all using the same code structure, within the code igniter framework.

The libraries, models and database should be the same across all the domains, the only difference should be the controllers and views that are used.

Preferably I would like to have a setup similar to this:

```
controllers/domain1.com/index.php
controllers/domain2.com/index.php
controllers/domain3.com/index.php
```

Does anyone have any experience modifying code igniter to work in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [loader class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) page in the manual and scroll down to the *Application "Packages"* part. Combine this with the part of running [Multiple Applications](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html) you should be able to be running multiple sites, with the same models and configs and avoid duplicating your code.

Comment: Thanks that works near perfectly. There are only two slight niggles 1) I need to call "add_package_path" in the __construct of every controller, is there anyway to load a package automatically and 2) it's not possible to move the config folder, is there some way I can make the same config folder be used for every site?

Comment: 1) Create your own controller as described here - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html - and use the construct to autoload the application package. 2) I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'moving the config folder'?

Comment: I'm doing something similar and what I did to load a package automatically is to add the package in the autoload file in the config folder. As for the config folder, I'm not aware of a way to have different applications share a config folder (I'm not sure if that's a good idea) but what I did is just have a config folder in each application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a manual page that describes how do you achieve this. Consult with [Running Multiple Applications with one CodeIgniter Installation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html).

The only difference is that it looks like you'll have to duplicate your models/configs as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I need to build a system on a different subdomain, since the default domain has an existing base codeigniter and it was not design to handle multiple domains or subdomains.

And part of my goals are:

- use the existing shared core objects in dir config, core, helpers and libraries.
- and the existing public dir files, but separate images/mysubdomain/* and other dirs/subdomain/*

And so this is what I have done.

- I've modified router.php in the same config dir and made a condition that routed a default controller in a separate dir inside mysubdomain/default if subdomain===true
- ie. /controllers/mysubdomain/default.php
- With a separate base controller that extends the main Controller inside /controllers/mysubdomain/.
- Then mysubdomain are defined (ie models/mysubdomain/* and views/mysubdomain/* in all my controllers in mysubdomain.

and this works perfectly as I need it.